# Is it possible to anonymously track someone's location via mobile apps?

Tags: iphone, blackberry, geolocation, location

Is it possible to anonymously track someone's location via mobile apps?

Assuming, of course, that the user consents and downloads an app that can in the background?

Comment: What do you mean by anonymously? That others can't see who you are tracking? Or that the system doesn't know who It's tracking?

Comment: Check here if you accept to be tracked everywhere by anyone.. uhm?

Comment: May be useful for pizza delivery guys or something ..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant: track someone without them opening the app and logging in. Anonymous was a poor word. The question was not clear. Sorry. And, yes, @Tungano, there are applications for delivery people (e.g., pizza, shuttle services, truckers) to get tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone OS 4 (coming "this summer") will allow you to run your app in the background, I believe that will allow you to keep track of the location.
http://www.apple.com/iphone/preview-iphone-os/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is both yes and no.

Yes, because Apple already supports this for MobileMe accounts, where you can track a registered iPhone through the "Find My iPhone" feature.

No, because you are not able to have an application run in the background on any current versions of the iPhone OS. It is possible that future versions will allow this, but not for any current versions.

So, Yes if you are Apple (which you are probably not) and no for the rest of us.

Claus

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is yes, it's possible. Since you can share your location in various forms already, nothing is stopping a service to allow entry to the public.